# How to load JSON with OkHttp in Android

Tags: android, json, android-json

I want develop android application for website. i want use `OkHttp` to load `Json` in my application. 
 I write this codes, but when start application and hide `progressDialog`, don't show me website datas (from json). 
**not** show any FC error (in logcat), **not** show any null exception error (in logcat), **just not show website datas in my application!**
my json link : [JSON link](http://tellfa.com/tafrihgah/?json=get_posts)

**Adapter codes:**

```
public class okHTTP_adapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<okHTTP_adapter.ViewHolder> {

    private List<okHTTP_dataProvider> mDataSet;
    private Context mContext;

    public okHTTP_adapter(Context context) {
        mContext = context;
        mDataSet = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        View view = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.recycler_raw, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.okHTTP_title.setText(mDataSet.get(position).getTitle());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mDataSet.size();
    }

    public void remove(int posistion) {
        mDataSet.remove(posistion);
        notifyItemRemoved(posistion);
    }

    public void add(List<okHTTP_dataProvider> models) {
        mDataSet.addAll(models);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        public TextView okHTTP_title;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            okHTTP_title = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.recycler_raw_title);
        }
    }
}
```

**AsyncTask class codes:**

```
public class okHTTP_info {
    private Context mContext;

    public void getOkHTTP_info(Context context) {
        mContext = context;
        new getInfo().execute(serverIP.getIP());
    }

    private class getInfo extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

        private String ou_response;
        private List<okHTTP_dataProvider> infoModels;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            CustomProcessDialog.createAndShow(mContext);
            infoModels = new ArrayList<>();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
            Request request = new Request.Builder()
                    .url(serverIP.getIP())
                    .build();

            Response response;
            try {
                response = client.newCall(request).execute();
                ou_response = response.body().string().trim();
                response.body().close();
                if (ou_response != null) {
                    JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(ou_response);
                    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                        infoModels.add(new okHTTP_dataProvider(
                                jsonObject.getString("title"),
                                jsonObject.getInt("id")));
                    }
                }
            } catch (IOException | JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return ou_response;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            CustomProcessDialog.dissmis();
        }
```

**Activity codes:**

```
public class okHTTP_Page extends AppCompatActivity {

    private RecyclerView recycler;
    private okHTTP_adapter adaper;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.ok_http__page);

        recycler = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.okHTTP_recycler);
        recycler.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recycler.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        adaper = new okHTTP_adapter(this);
        recycler.setAdapter(adaper);

        okHTTP_info info = new okHTTP_info();
        info.getOkHTTP_info(this);
    }
}
```

**Attention :** Please don't give me negative points. i am amateur and i need your helps! thanks all <3

Comment: In your response, there is `id` and `title` for many keys. You are looking for which one?

Comment: posts title and posts id. please help me. i really need this tutorial my friend

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are parsing the JSON in wrong way. Try this inside `if(ou_response != null)` block:

```
try {
    JSONObject response = new JSONObject(ou_response);
    JSONArray postsArray = response.getJSONArray("posts");

    for (int i = 0; i < postsArray.length(); i++) {
        JSONObject postObject = postsArray.getJSONObject(i);
        int id = postObject.getInt("id");
        String title = postObject.getString("title");
        Log.i("Data", "Post id: " + id );
        Log.i("Data", "Post title: " + title );
        //Use the title and id as per your requirement
    }
} 
catch (JSONException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Thanks man, but now show title and id in logcat. but in aplication not show!!! why not show in appliction and show in logcat?

Comment: He is logging the id and title, you just need to use id and title somewhere else.

Comment: @AntónioPaulo, can you send me code or simple code? please

Comment: @FeedBack Inside the for that Prerak created you have `int id` and `String title`. Just use those as you want.

Answer (score 0):

First your json is a Json Object, something similar as this:

```
{.....,"posts":[{"id":5.....}].....}
```

So you should get first the jsonObject and them get the jsonArray which is with the "categories" tag, like this:

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(ou_response);
JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONObject("posts");
```

And then continue with your own code.

Second you should notify changes with  `notifyDataSetChanged();` in `onPostExecuted()` because It's not possible to modify a view in other thread, only in the UIThread.

Comment: Print out a log to know if you are getting the data as @Prerak Sola suggested